# Pull Salesforce data into Azure

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-lake

requirement is to replicate few Salesforce objects into Azure data lake.  Since I am new to Azure can someone please help with the tools or connections needed to ingest data from salesforce into azure data lake. I need real time processing

Comment: You can use [Workbench APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_using_workbench.htm) to pull data using Rest APIs services.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data from salesforce to Azure data lake using Azure data factory.

> Azure data factory is the cloud-based ETL and data integration service that allows you to create data-driven workflows for orchestrating data movement and transforming data at scale. Using Azure Data Factory, you can create and schedule data-driven workflows (called pipelines) that can ingest data from disparate data stores. You can build complex ETL processes that transform data visually with data flows

In Azure data factory, use Copy Data activity in the pipeline and connect source to salesforce connector, sink to Azure data lake storage connector.

Reference: [Copy data from salesforce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce#get-started)

1. Create a `pipeline` and add `Copy Data` activity to it. Provide source and sink(destination) data store connections to copy data.

[image]

2. For source, create a linked service connection with **salesforce as data store** and provide the details.

[image]
[image]

3. For sink, create a new linked service with **data lake storage as data store** and provide the connection details.

[image]
[image]

4. Once the connection and mapping is setup, you can test it by running in **debug** mode.

[image]

5. You can also run it by adding **trigger** to the pipeline.

[image]

6. Azure data factory provides various [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) options based on the requirement. You can schedule them to run per requirement.

[image]